# Make its question given below

Tags: grammar, word-usage, questions, word-order

If I want to ask question, how should I ask?

Answer is given below;

Akbar was the third king.

Comment: Are you possibly asking for Akbar's ordinality - was he first, second, twenty-fifth? That question was addressed [**here**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/4587/32).

Comment: Which part of the answer are you questioning? _Who_ was Akbar? _Which_ king (first, second or third) was Akbar? _Who_ was the third king? _What_ (king, jester, prince) was Akbar? @CoolHandLouis has tried to cover many possibilities, but which are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Who was Akbar?
Akbar was **the third king.**

Who was the third king?
**Akbar** was the third king.

Was Akbar the first, second, or third king?
Akbar was the **third** king.

Was Akbar the third jester, prince, or king?
Akbar was the third **king**.

Note that additional context is needed for these questions to be answerable.  For example, these questions would make sense if a student was taking an exam and had just read a short story about Akbar, the various kings, etc.  But just going up to someone randomly and asking "Who was the third king?" would just get you a blank stare.