# What noun or a phrase would fit well to refer to a person's "placement" in the family?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request

What noun or a phrase would fit well to refer to a person's "placement" in the family, among his or her siblings?:

> She is the fourth and the last child in her family. Her siblings are
>   all brothers and the youngest one is ten years older than her. Girls
>   **of this family status** are usually more mature and less shallow.

[How can I ask a person in which order in his family among the siblings?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79198/how-can-i-ask-a-person-in-which-order-in-his-family-among-the-siblings) is seeking how to ask a question about one of the constituent factors, while I'm looking for a term that would refer to a particular combination of constituent factors.

To use an example, letter "l" is the third letter in both "owls" and "delamination". That that letter is the third one is a constituent factor that plays its part in both combinations.

However, the combinations are quite different:

- one word is a combination of four letters, the other one is a combination of twelve;
- in the first combination there are more letters preceding "l" than those following it, in the second combination it is the other way around;
- in the first combination, letter "l" it is surrounded by consonants, in the second combination by vowels;
- etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I ask a person in which order in his family among the siblings?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79198/how-can-i-ask-a-person-in-which-order-in-his-family-among-the-siblings)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83516/discussion-on-question-by-brilliant-what-noun-or-a-phrase-would-fit-well-to-refe).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common expression at least related to this is [birth order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birth_order).

From a psychological perspective, birth order is a contentious theory, and I personally don't put much stock in it. Wikipedia opens its article by saying:

> Birth order refers to the order a child is born in their family; *first-born* and *second-born* are examples. Birth order is often believed to have a profound and lasting effect on psychological development. This assertion has been repeatedly challenged ... Nevertheless, the notion that birth-order significantly influences personality continues to have a strong presence in pop psychology and popular culture.

From an English perspective, however, you could say:

> Girls of this **birth order** are usually more mature and less shallow.

The term says nothing about the spacing between siblings, but your example mentions the ten-year gap explicitly, so it would still work in that context.

Answer (score 3):

**Such girls** are usually more mature ...

You could also write:

Girls who are the youngest child in the family, whose next oldest sibling is older by ten years, and whose older siblings are all male, tend to be more mature.