# What is your para?

Tags: usage

To know a person's number or order among his /her siblings can this question be asked or is there any alternate?

What is your para?

Answer (score 2):

English doesn't have a word specifically for your position among you siblings agewise (at least as far as I am aware).

If you wish to describe your position, you would typically either use "oldest child" (or possibly "eldest child"), "middle child", or "youngest child", or ordinals ("second child", "third child", etc.)  Using "first child" instead of "oldest child" is pretty rare, but would be understood.  "Middle child" applies to any position that isn't the oldest or the youngest.  'Child' can be replaced by 'sibling' for all of these, but is more common for oldest/middle/youngest than ordinals.

If you wish to find out what position someone else is in, you would have to ask something along the lines of

> Are you the oldest sibling?

or

> Are your siblings older or younger than you?

And usually the person you're asking will describe where they fall in age order.

Comment: My question is how to ask a wh question about some one's position among ones siblings,  Can we ask as below?    How manyth child of your parents are you?       Or  what is your para?

Comment: @AltafJahangir Neither of those questions are good English.  'Para' is not an English word.  As I said above, there isn't a really good way to ask this question in English. You're much better off with the indirect options I suggested, even though they don't specifically ask for the information you want.