# How do I ask this?

Tags: phrase-choice

Is there a specific phrase I can use to ask someone:
What their “rank” amongst their siblings is? 
To know whether they are the youngest,middle or oldest sibling?

Comment: @ColleenV No it doesn’t but thank you anyway!

Comment: [How can I ask a person in which order in his family among the siblings?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/79198/9161) that is linked in the "What noun or phrase..." question is the one I mean to close this one as a duplicate of. I had the wrong link on my clipboard.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes it does,thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a specific phrase.

People might ask: **Where in the family do you fit?**

Or, more directly, **Are you the oldest or the youngest or somewhere in the middle?**

Possibly: **Have you older or younger siblings?**

Comment: Is “Where in the family do you fit?” Commonly used? Will the person immediately understand what I mean? 

And thank you for answering!

Comment: Native English speakers should understand it without a problem.

Answer (score -1):

(American English)

"Rank" has the connotation of indicating one is superior to the other. I think you are really asking about the birth order of the siblings. It's important to figure out how many siblings they have first and then you ask about what their order of birth is.

Typically the conversation will go something like this

> A: Do you have any brother's or sister's?
>
> B: Yes two brothers and a sister
>
> A: Older or younger?
>
> B: George and Gary are older and Claire is younger

^^By knowing that there are 2 older siblings and 1 younger, you can conclude the person you are talking to was the 3rd born in the family.

If you just ask someone are they the youngest, oldest, or middle child without knowing how many siblings the person has your interest does not seem as genuine. You also exclude the possibility that the person could be an only child.

Comment: @Cretting Thank you for the explanation! Another person suggested using “Where in the family do you fit?” Is that something you would use?

Comment: @Manar That is not something I would use or have heard while living on the east coast of the United States (It might be popular in other regions but I am not certain). If someone said that to me, I would ask the person to clarify.  “Where in the family do you fit?” Sounds more like you are asking what the person does for the family as opposed to the order of birth of siblings.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to play Sherlock Holmes and try to deduce where they are among their siblings by interrogating them instead of just asking them directly.