# How do I ask someone his/her position in his family(among his siblings)?

Tags: word-usage, politeness

I want to learn a person's order/position in his family i.e., among his siblings. So can I say:

> *"Where do you rank among your siblings?"*

Is this usage correct? If not, can anyone provide me with some other better question?

Comment: No, ask "Are you the eldest?" See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/79198/how-can-i-ask-a-person-in-which-order-in-his-family-among-the-siblings

Comment: Note: culturally most English speakers don't care to much about this.  For example, we use the same word for "older brother" as "younger brother".

Comment: Being the oldest or youngest or middle matters more than any other order for siblings. There are often cultural assumptions that the oldest would lead, youngest would follow and a "middle child" would be a peace-keeper and flexible.

If you really care about the order, ask that. "Rank" implies better/worse than comparisons, which is usually inappropriate as a general question.