# How to ask what nth?

Tags: word-choice

If you don't get the question, that's exactly what I want to know.

Imagine we have a ordered list of fruits.

```
["Apple", "Banana", "Peach", "Orange"]
```

I want the 3rd fruit in that list. But you don't know which one I want.
How one asks which member in the sequence I want.

like:

> What nth fruit do you want?

Now, I know that this is wrong. I'm looking for the right expression to ask this. I hope my question is now clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the position of a person in a sequence](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4587/asking-the-position-of-a-person-in-a-sequence)

Comment: 3rd, not '3th'. [Ordinal numbers](https://www.ego4u.com/en/cram-up/vocabulary/numbers/ordinal)

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thanks. Edited.